# how do i return only a part of value in a row using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table i have in SQL server,

```
Title           value
-------------   -------
abc_ef_1_123    53.2
abc_ef_1_1      43.2
abc_ef_1_11     23.1
abc_ef_1_12     45.2
abc_ef_1_13     56.4
def_cef_3_23    98.1
def_cef_3_3     53.2
def_cef_3_12    43.2
def_cef_3_13    23.1
def_cef_3_123   45.2
```

Need to group the rows by values before the third '_' as below,

select title, max (value) as value from table1 group by title;

the results should be,

```
title     value
--------- -----
abc_ef_1  56.4
def_cef_3 98.1
```

Please assist.

Comment: Just for posterity, this is why you don't invent your own column format. Each of those tokens in the string should have been different columns probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will do the job neatly (replace "Test" with your table name):

```
;with cte as (
  select 
    left(Title, len(Title) - charindex('_', reverse(Title) + '_')) as Title, 
    Value
  from Test
)

select cte.Title, MAX(cte.value)
from cte
group by cte.Title
```

now, to shoot exactly for the third underscore, 
create the function instructed by the article below, then apply the following query to get the desired result. putting the messy logic inline is a bit counter intuitive so using a function like that is the way to to.
[http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30497](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30497/)

query using the Sql Server function from the link above:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
    LEFT(Title, dbo.CHARINDEX2('_', Title, 3) - 1) as Title, 
    Value
  from Test
)

select cte.Title, MAX(cte.value)
from cte
group by cte.Title
```

good luck!

Comment: Just noting the assumption that there are always exactly three underscores in the text.

Comment: well i did this with assumption that last underscore is the the splitting point, being third of course in the sample. I have edited my answer to cater for your exact scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
with
  sample_data (title, value) as (
    select 'abc_ef_1_123' , 53.2 from dual union all
    select 'abc_ef_1_1'   , 43.2 from dual union all
    select 'abc_ef_1_11'  , 23.1 from dual union all
    select 'abc_ef_1_12'  , 45.2 from dual union all
    select 'abc_ef_1_13'  , 56.4 from dual union all
    select 'def_cef_3_23' , 98.1 from dual union all
    select 'def_cef_3_3'  , 53.2 from dual union all
    select 'def_cef_3_12' , 43.2 from dual union all
    select 'def_cef_3_13' , 23.1 from dual union all
    select 'def_cef_3_123', 45.2 from dual
  )
select   substr(title, 1, instr(title, '_', 1, 3) - 1) as title, max(value) as value
from     sample_data
group by substr(title, 1, instr(title, '_', 1, 3) - 1);

TITLE       VALUE
----------- -----
abc_ef_1     56.4
def_cef_3    98.1
```

The main takeaway is that you can group by any expressions you like, you are not restricted to grouping by columns. Also, you must repeat the same expression in `GROUP BY` and in `SELECT`; alas, the alias (name, label) given in SELECT can't be used as is in `GROUP BY`. (If the expression was much more complex than in this case, you would create the alias first, in a subquery, and then use it in an aggregate outer query.)

Of course, in this case it's even worse, since you want to use the same column name, `title`, in the output. If you were to group by `title` in `GROUP BY`, that would group by the column in the input table, not by the expression in `SELECT`. This is why what you are doing in your output is generally a bad practice: since the new column is not the same as what you have in the base table, give it a different name, not `title`. I simply followed your lead - reluctantly.

Comment: I am trying it on SQL server. My bad that i didnt mention it before. Instr isnt available in SQL server

Comment: @Chand - It wasn't just mentioning SQL Server in the post, the tag was wrong too (I see you fixed that now). In any case - find the analogous function in SQL Server, that does the same thing as `INSTR` does in Oracle. Perhaps the syntax of `SUBSTR` is different too - I don't know SQL Server, perhaps others will give you better advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(title, '[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*', 1, 1),
       max(value)
from t
group by regexp_substr(title, '[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*', 1, 1);
```

Comment: I am trying it on SQL server. My bad that i didnt mention it before. Instr isnt available in SQL server

Answer (score 0):

> Select
>
> Left(Title, charindex(‘[ _ ]’ , Title, charindex(‘[ _ ]’ , Title,
>   charindex(’[ _ ]’ , Title))))
>
> ,Max(Value)
>
> From   Tbl
>
> Group by
>
> Left(Title, charindex(‘[ _ ]’ , Title, charindex(‘[ _ ]’ , Title,
>   charindex(’[ _ ]’ , Title))))